# unknown filesystem error after reinstalling linux

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, bios, grubrescue

After reinstalling 18.04 over 19.10 alongside Win10, the boot fails with the following error:

```
error: unknown filesystem.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue >`
```

From what I understood from similar questions the problem seems to be locating the `normal.mod` file, well I found mine is in `(hd0, msdos6)/boot/grub/x86_64-efi`, but when I try to set the prefix to this, it appends `i386-pc` to the location where it "searches" the file.

```
set root=(hd0,msdos6)
set prefix=(hd0,msdos6)/boot/grub/x86_64-efi
insmod normal
error: file /boot/grub/x86-64-efi/i386-pc/normal.mod not found
```

Comment: msdos file system is for windows, you need to have an ext4 partition for ubuntu

Comment: @kcdtv the partition in question has is `ext2`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up up following the instructions for [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) which fixed the boot loader.